# QGIS and Google Earth Engine

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine

I have been trying to display a satellite image from Google Earth Engine in QGIS.

Then using both the QGIS and Google Earth Engine I want to process the satellite image.

Is it possible?

Comment: You need to [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/341795/edit) the question to give more details of what you have been trying to display an image.   It strays into two question territory when you ask about using QGIS and GEE to process the same image, do you mean simultaneously, side by side, something else?    You should add more detail of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: https://github.com/gee-community/qgis-earthengine-plugin

Comment: Google Earth Engine plugin for QGIS is available now. Check out this tutorial how to install and to use it https://www.geodose.com/2019/12/google-earth-engine-qgis-plugin-tutorial.html?m=1